# (proof writing attempt)Let (X, d) be a metric space. We say that $S \subseteq X$ is bounded if there is $c \gt 0$ such that $d(x, y) \le c$ for any...

Tags: limits, solution-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> Let (X, d) be a metric space. We say that $S \subseteq X$ is bounded if there is $c \gt 0$ such that $d(x, y) \le c$ for any $x, y \in X$. Show that $S \subseteq X$ is bounded if, and only if, S is contained in some ball of $X$.

I can visualize the answer but I'm having trouble to write the ansewer. This is my attempt:

(=>) If $S \subseteq X$ is bounded then $d(x, y) \le c$ and by ball definition $B(x,\delta) = \{ y \in X: d(x,y)\lt \delta \}$ now taking $c = \delta$ we have that $B(x,\delta) = \{ y \in X: d(x,y)\le c \}$ which is a closed ball.

(<=) If the ball exists then $B(x,\delta) = \{ y \in X: d(x,y)\le \delta \}$ so $\delta$ is a limit therefore taking $\delta = c$ we have that $S \subseteq X$ is bounded.

Thanks.

Comment: In the forward direction, $c$ is not fixed, it depends upon $x,y$. So you can't take $\delta=c$. And the (<=) proof needs some more explanation.

Comment: The forward direction is OK (@PNDas $c$ is given by the definition of boundedness) but you have to make *explicit* that you *choose* some $x\in S$ (anyone) to be the center of your closed ball (and that $S$ is contained in that ball!), and handle separately the case $S=\varnothing$. Btw, there is a typo in your definition of boundedness: it should be for any $x,y\in S$, not $X$.

Comment: For $\Leftarrow$, $c=\delta$ does not work because we want $d(u,v)\le c$ for *any* $u,v\in S$ (possibly both $\ne x$, anyway $x$ is not necessarily $\in S$).

Comment: Does Christoph's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730533) answer yours?

Comment: @AnneBauval you are right. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that comment.

Comment: OP in $\Rightarrow$, use a notation different from $B(.,.)$ for the *closed* ball, e.g. $\overline B(x,\delta) = \{ y \in X: d(x,y)\le c \}$.